# running command line "ping -S IP HOST" in c and get exit code

Tags: c

i need to run a ping to HOST though IP
i found the syntax is ping -S IP HOST

how can i achieve this programmatic in a c++ program?
and get the return exit code of this command?

i tried

```
char command[255];
sprintf(command, "ping -S %s %s", ip, host);
system(command);
```

but the return value is of the system function

under a windows environment

thank you!

Comment: "but the return code is of the system function" - huh what? That function doesn't have a return code, it's not a command line tool. It's a function, it has a return value, and its return value is the exit code of the command it runs.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system states, that in case of error, system returns -1 and otherwise it **does** return the exit code of the command.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention - i'm working in windows

Comment: @starrify No, **you** read the man page. "The system() function returns the exit status of the shell as returned by waitpid(2), or -1 if an error occurred when invoking fork(2) or waitpid(2)."

Comment: Look, guys, the problem here is that the OP writes " the return value is of the system function" but doesn't tell us what that value is and how it differs from what is expected. On Windows the WEXITSTATUS function just returns its argument, so it's irrelevant whether you use it or not.

Comment: @starrify No, we're talking about Windows. Who the heck knows what H2CO3 is quoting from ... the Mac manual, maybe?

Comment: @JimBalter Well, I see.. XD

Comment: @starrify Actually I think he's quoting from FreeBSD. Anyway, he's a bit of an arrogant hothead, as you can see. The return value from waitpid is NOT the program's exit status, of course ... you have to apply WEXITSTATUS.

Comment: @JimBalter Aha I've been seeing this guy for quite a long time. XD An arrogant hothead critic & good boy, of course.. :D

Comment: @starrify He is a good boy; that > 100K rep was earned -- but he is a bit sure of himself even when he ought not be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, instead use IcmpSendEcho2 to implement the ping functionality.
Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366051%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks man, can you please direct me how to implement the "-S IP" parameter i'd use in the regular ping command?

Answer (score 3):

To get the return status of your command in the [`system`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/system/) function, use the [`WEXITSTATUS`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/wait/) macro:

```
int ret = system("foo");
printf("foo return %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(ret));
```

Check the other `W` macros, they can be usefull.

**EDIT**: On Windows, it seems to be different. You can use directly the return value of the `system` function as the return value of your command ([see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx))

> If command is not NULL, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter.

Comment: @dan So what? `system` is a POSIX function and WEXITSTATUS is the macro to use to get the exit status. Now, whether the OP actually has a POSIX ping command installed on his system is another matter.

Comment: @JimBalter I agree but on Windows u don't 'need' it :) [Windows System Man](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @dan Writing portable code is preferable whether necessary or not.